# React Router Dom doesn't redirect but the URL changes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I'm developing a React TypeScript Dashboard Template, everyone that need a Template with TS.

Everything was going ok until I started to develop the routing feature.

I have a common route file

```js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from "../views/Home";
import About from "../views/About";

export default function Routes() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={`/`} component={Home} />
        <Route path={`/about`} component={About} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

**My question: I have a sidebar to navigate inside the dashboard, here is the issue. When I click in a Link to redirect to another page, the URL changes, but the page keeps. If I type the URL an press Enter, changes the page**

My pages are rendered inside a Panel, follow the code.

```js
import React from "react";
import "./index";
import Sidebar from "./components/Sidebar";
import { Panel } from "./global";
import Home from "./views/Home";
import Routes from "./routes";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="dashboard">
      <Sidebar title="TS React Template" />
      <Panel>
        <Routes />
      </Panel>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**The Panel is only a Styled Components div**

The sidebar code:

```js
.
.
.

const Sidebar = (props: { title: string }) => {
  const { title } = props;

  return (
    <div className="sidebar">
      <Router>
        <ListItem className="title" button>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <DashboardRoundedIcon />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText>{title}</ListItemText>
        </ListItem>

        <List disablePadding dense>
          <Link to="/">
            <ListItem button>
              <ListItemIcon>
                <HomeRoundedIcon />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText>Home</ListItemText>
              <Arrow className="state" />
            </ListItem>
          </Link>

          <Link to="/about">
            <ListItem button>
              <ListItemIcon>
                <InfoRoundedIcon />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText>About</ListItemText>
              <Arrow className="state" />
            </ListItem>
          </Link>
        </List>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I've never worked doing a dashboard from zero, and I don't know if I'm in the correct way, but I didn't find a React Typescript Dashboard Template anywhere, so I'm trying to contributing to React Community. If you can help more in the project, this is the github url: https://github.com/MatheusCoxxxta/React-TypeScript-Dashboard-Template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug probably in your `Sidebar` component. You wrapped the code inside another `Router`. Remove the `Router` wrapper and it should work

The reason for this is that, a `Router` will created a "sealed" environment in which any action inside it that cause a change in URL (i.e `Link` component or `history.push`) will cause the page render the `Route` defined inside that `Router` only. Here in your app you have 2 `Router` environment and your `Link` is inside the nested one. Thus when you click the link it will try to find the `Route` that match the path inside the nested `Router`, which is none.

When you remove `Router` wrapper from your `Sidebar` component, the error you mention is expected as now this `Sidebar` component is not belong to any `Router` component. There are several ways to put the `Sidebar` inside a `Router`, but what I recommend is that, you should make the `Router` wrap around the root component (maybe in `index.js`) so that you can avoid all of these problem.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowsweRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

Also it's worth to mention that using `a` tag is not a "fix" to your problem. It basically defeat the whole purpose of using `react-router`

Comment: In this case, removing the `Router`, I have this error `"You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>"`... I'm using an `<a href="/">` while I try to correct the Link problem.

Comment: As the error said, you are using `Panel` outside of any `Router` component. I edited my answer to give you more info about this